# How do I see unplayed podcasts?

Tags: macos, podcasts

On Catalina, I have a station set up to show unplayed podcasts.    Right now it shows a podcast from yesterday "Science Friday Part 2", but not "Science Friday Part 1", which I had to find by looking in "episodes".

It also doesn't show several other podcasts which I found in "Recently Updated", but which I haven't listened to (I'm tracking which episodes I listen to).

I have given up trying to listen to podcasts on my phone and watch because they won't synchronize with my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I personally also gave up on podcasts on the Mac. Maybe someone has a great app, but for me using Overcast made my phone / watch always with me and “perfect for this job” so my Mac can take a rest from podcast duties and only need to work when I listen to music and find it’s better than HomePod / watch / phone / iPad.

- https://overcast.fm/

I know this doesn’t directly answer your question, but really - consider not solving this at all on the Mac is my advice. Since Catalina, Big Sur, Monterey have come and gone, I still haven’t needed to use Apple podcast app anywhere and overcast is still what I’m happy to pay for and use since it makes me happy and saves me time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Overcast](https://overcast.fm/), which is a great iOS app, but also runs pretty well as an M1 mac app.

Comment: I think I tried it, but I didn't figure out how to synchronize it with my Mac's podcast app.

Comment: I just installed it on my M1 iMac, entered my email and a password the subscribed to a podcast.  Did the same thing with my phone, and the podcast showed up there too!   I expect they will synchronize when I start listening.   Thanks!!!