# Are Podcasts on iOS and Podcasts on macOS supposed to sync?

Tags: podcasts

Is progress in listening to podcasts on iOS and macOS intentionally out of sync? My bookmarks are (mostly) synced across devices, but my play history never is. Is that intentional?

Comment: They are meant to sync across all devices but I agree they don't

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using Apple apps for podcasts unless you only have one device for listening. Even then, check out Overcast.

- https://overcast.fm/

For your needs, the [tool to use is Overcast third party app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379516/5472). It’s free and paying $10 to remove the ads makes me a very happy customer.

Comment: Yeah I'm really struggling with the continuous downgrading of Apple's apps (Music, Podcasts, TV, App Store). I'm not sure what their plan is.

Comment: Hmm @orome all Apple’s other apps make me very happy, including the ones you mention. Podcasts however, just I am not their target user and that’s been clear since day one. Seems more a design fit mismatch and not that anything degrades from where I sit.